# Why doesn't this jquery function repeat after both .animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any reason as to why this function doesn't repeat?

```
var $title = $('#title');
var animateGlow = function($title) {
    $title.animate({ 'color':'red' }, 2000)
        .animate({ 'color':'blue' }, 2000, function() {
            animateGlow(this);
    });
};
animateGlow($title);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `$(this)` instead of `this`, native objects doesn't have `animate` function

Use

```
var $title = $('#title');
var animateGlow = function ($title) {
    $title.animate({
        'color': 'red'
    }, 2000).animate({
        'color': 'blue'
    }, 2000, function () {
        animateGlow($(this));
    });
};
animateGlow($title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function with an element reference instead of a jQuery object. Wrap the element using `$(this)`, or better yet use the one that's already in the `$title` variable:

```
var $title = $('#title');
var animateGlow = function($title) {
    $title.animate({ 'color':'red' }, 2000)
        .animate({ 'color':'blue' }, 2000, function() {
            animateGlow($title);
    });
};
animateGlow($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) method:

```
var $title = $('#title');
var animateGlow = function($title) {
    $title.animate({ 'color':'red' }, 2000).end()
        .animate({ 'color':'blue' }, 2000, function() {
            animateGlow($title);//replaced this with $title 
    });
};
animateGlow($title);
```